# Replacing outer panel of old window

Tags: windows

Firstly, I don't know exactly what the correct terms are for these things, so bear with me. I've spent the better part of today trying to find a solution to this, but I must just be set on searching the wrong terms over and over again..

Basically, I have a window where the outer parts are made of 2 individual glass panels. Each has 2 spring latches at the bottom of the panel (see images) that let me lock each at different levels. However, only 1 of the 4 latches actually works or even appears to have a spring inside. That panel is "permanently" set as the top of the outer side, because it's the only one that actually stays up to keep the outer layer closed with it's single working latch.

The issue is that with the order they are set into the window, if there are heavy rains, water hits the top panel, which is more inset than the lower one, and trickles behind the bottom one, occasionally leaking/dripping into the bottom of the frame itself.

How should I go about fixing this? I would assume that I could either replace just the latch, or the whole pane/frame itself. My googling and searching the orange/green/blue stores is coming up with nothing.

[image: Close up of latch, broken, no spring]

[image: Window in place]

Comment: Here are some links, etc. to get you on the right path: https://www.google.com/search?q=storm+window+slide+bolt+replacement&oq=storm+window+slide+bolts&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30l6j0i390.10688j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

These are "sashes". Double-hung windows have two operable (hung) sashes. Single-hung windows have one operable and one stationary sash.

The broken part is often called a "[slide bolt](https://www.google.com/search?q=storm%20window%20sash%20slide%20bolt)". I suggest that you either procure a replacement part, or manufacture one out of aluminum, plastic, or hardwood which you could screw, rivet, or glue in place in a permanent manner to hold the upper sash at the top for proper water drainage.

Comment: Yeah, at this point gluing in the bolts seems like the best/easiest option. It's somewhat of a temporary living situation, so more of a slight annoyance than something I feel the *need* to fix. The previous owner glued (jammed, somehow?) the wooden upper inside sash to the top of the frame, so it's not like I need to move this one anyway...